# Android: Error converting bytecode to dex after adding firebase dependencies

Tags: android, firebase

This is my app level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried:

1. Building/Cleaning the project.
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart.
3. Enabling multidex gives new errors and does not work.
4. Version 9.6.1 of the firebase-messaging library builds the apk but app crashes on start up.
5. Updated the versions of google support repository/play services.
6. I use only the messaging library so different version numbers are not the problem. Adding the firebase-core library seems to be of no use.
7. Used API level 25 as well.

Needless to say, I double-checked the project-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have searched and tried many related answers on stackoverflow but failed to come up with a solution.

**Possible solution:**
Version 9.6.1 builds the apk but crashes the app on startup. Maybe the problem is with the version.

Here is the error:

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zze;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: have you add the multidex in your manifest

Comment: @AssemMahrous I had an Application class which was in the manifest already. `attachBaseContext()` was overriden and `Multidex.install(this)` was added as stated in another SO answer.

Comment: I copy/pasted your build.gradle contents into an empty app and was able to build without error.  That suggests to me there is some differences in the repository versions we are using, although you indicate you have updated to latest versions.  You might try using the Android Studio _New Project_ wizard to create an empty app, cut/paste your build file contents and see if you get the same error.